# Set a Default Document to be viewed in File viewer

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, view, file-upload

I have created a document library that is connected with a file viewer. once loading the page the file viewer shows nothing. We have to select a document to be viewed. What I want the file viewer should select automatically the latest uploaded document in the document library and view it in the File Viewer.

Comment: I have the same question and would expect either an option for the library web part to define a default selection or for the file web part to select the first item from the connected source. That does not seem to be the case. I find the default implementation with an empty view useless.

Answer (score 1):

Per my knowledge, file viewer web part does not support dynamically displaying the documents. You can connect the File viewer web part to a Document library web part and show files dynamically based on what a user selects in the Document library web part.